# Iterate over 4d and 3d array and return the values in the shape of 4d again

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, normalization

I have a `4D` array of shape `(10, 100, 32, 64)` called `first_channel`. Then, I go over each one of 10 elements in the first dimension, and take the resulting 3D array of shape `(100, 32, 64)`. I go over each one of the 100 elements of the first dimension, do min-max scaling and return back to the shape of the 4D array after scaling the 2D sub-arrays of shape `(32, 64)`.

```
for record_num, record in enumerate(first_channel):
    for frame_num, frame in enumerate(record):
        data_min = np.min(frame)
        data_max = np.max(frame)
        normalized_data = (frame - data_min) / (data_max - data_min)
```

I tried this approach but the problem is that the length of the list at the end of the day is 1000, so I see that it is combining each one of the 10 records with the 100 frames. However, I need to do the min-max scaling for each one of the 100 frames and get the values returned in the shape of `(100, 32, 64)`, then return it in the shape of the `4D` as (10, 100, 32, 64)`.

Comment: You have a double loop, but only one append in the inner loop.  So by basic list logic the result is one list.  You want a list of lists, which requires 2 levels of list append.  Practice with something small to fat a clearer idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(10, size = (3, 3, 3, 3))

normalized_data = (data - data.min((2, 3)).reshape(3, 3, 1, 1))/(data.max((2, 3)) - data.min((2, 3))).reshape(3, 3, 1, 1)
```

output:

```
data = 
[[[[5 0 3]
   [3 7 9]
   [3 5 2]]

  [[4 7 6]
   [8 8 1]
   [6 7 7]]

  [[8 1 5]
   [9 8 9]
   [4 3 0]]]


 [[[3 5 0]
   [2 3 8]
   [1 3 3]]

  [[3 7 0]
   [1 9 9]
   [0 4 7]]

  [[3 2 7]
   [2 0 0]
   [4 5 5]]]


 [[[6 8 4]
   [1 4 9]
   [8 1 1]]

  [[7 9 9]
   [3 6 7]
   [2 0 3]]

  [[5 9 4]
   [4 6 4]
   [4 3 4]]]]
normalized_data = 
[[[[0.55555556 0.         0.33333333]
   [0.33333333 0.77777778 1.        ]
   [0.33333333 0.55555556 0.22222222]]

  [[0.42857143 0.85714286 0.71428571]
   [1.         1.         0.        ]
   [0.71428571 0.85714286 0.85714286]]

  [[0.88888889 0.11111111 0.55555556]
   [1.         0.88888889 1.        ]
   [0.44444444 0.33333333 0.        ]]]


 [[[0.375      0.625      0.        ]
   [0.25       0.375      1.        ]
   [0.125      0.375      0.375     ]]

  [[0.33333333 0.77777778 0.        ]
   [0.11111111 1.         1.        ]
   [0.         0.44444444 0.77777778]]

  [[0.42857143 0.28571429 1.        ]
   [0.28571429 0.         0.        ]
   [0.57142857 0.71428571 0.71428571]]]


 [[[0.625      0.875      0.375     ]
   [0.         0.375      1.        ]
   [0.875      0.         0.        ]]

  [[0.77777778 1.         1.        ]
   [0.33333333 0.66666667 0.77777778]
   [0.22222222 0.         0.33333333]]

  [[0.33333333 1.         0.16666667]
   [0.16666667 0.5        0.16666667]
   [0.16666667 0.         0.16666667]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compute all the quantities directly, without reshaping anything:

```
mn = first_channel.min(axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True)
mx = first_channel.max(axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True)
first_channel -= mn
first_channel /= mx - mn
```

This does the operation in-place, which is probably what you want for a sufficiently large array. Keep in mind that this will run into problems on channels with no dynamic range, since `mx - mn` will be zero, and is the divisor in the second step.

Comment: I think axis should be (2, 3) instead of (3,4)

Comment: @Atila. You're absolutely right. Thanks for the catch. Fixed